# How do you express this in YAML?

Tags: yaml

```
[2, "single", {"avoidEscape": true, "allowTemplateLiterals": true}]
```

Answer (score 2):

That is already correct YAML. But if you want can do away with the unnecessary double quotes:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
[2, "single", {"avoidEscape": true, "allowTemplateLiterals": true}]
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

gives:

```
[2, single, {avoidEscape: true, allowTemplateLiterals: true}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- 2
- single
- allowTemplateLiterals: true
  avoidEscape: true
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought perhaps there was a way to express the third parameter in a more YAML style.

Comment: @AdamGering, by saying YAML style, I guess you mean present map in another way. I have changed the answer :)